# Git: Added sub module to a XCode project then GitBox crashes when I open it

Tags: xcode, git, git-submodules, gitbox

I added a Git repo as a submodule to my existing project which is also Git managed, I did these in command line, and I use GitBox to manage my projects, then when I open GitBox, it just crashed, I tried many times and even restarted the machine.

> Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object
>   cannot be nil (key: _NSTaskExecutablePath)' abort() called terminate
>   called throwing an exception
>
> Application Specific Backtrace 1: 0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff92a3c716 __exceptionPreprocess + 198 1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x00007fff8f2b3470 objc_exception_throw + 43 2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff92acaf07 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 135 3
>   Foundation                          0x00007fff8f6cd732
>   -[NSConcreteTask setLaunchPath:] + 194 4   Gitbox                              0x000000010001d779 Gitbox + 120697 5   Gitbox
>   0x000000010001cfb7 Gitbox + 118711 6   Gitbox
>   0x000000010005b6eb Gitbox + 374507 7   Gitbox
>   0x000000010000687b Gitbox + 26747 8   Gitbox
>   0x000000010005a3cc Gitbox + 369612 9   Gitbox
>   0x000000010005a6cc Gitbox + 370380 10  Gitbox
>   0x000000010001c7ec Gitbox + 116716 11  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00007fff8e881f3d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15 12 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8e87e0fa
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8 13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8e883104 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 275 14 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff929de81e __CFRunLoopRun
>   + 1614 15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff929dddd2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290 16  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff98145774 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209 17  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff98145512 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356 18  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff981453a3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62 19 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff93d29fa3 _DPSNextEvent +
>   685 20  AppKit                              0x00007fff93d29862
>   -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128 21  AppKit                              0x00007fff93d20c03
>   -[NSApplication run] + 517 22  AppKit                              0x00007fff93cc5656 NSApplicationMain + 869 23  Gitbox
>   0x00000001000028c1 Gitbox + 10433 24  Gitbox
>   0x0000000100001d94 Gitbox + 7572 25  ???
>   0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2

I wanted to remove the Gitbox settings and make it as a newly installed app, but did not find it. What else can I try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to uninstall Gitbox and lose your repo list - just delete Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.oleganza.gitbox.savedState/

Answer (score 1):

Get an uninstallation app (e.g. AppCleaner) and remove everything it finds but the gitbox app itself.

Then relaunch gitbox - unfortunately you will have to re-add the repos you were working with to gitbox but this will get you past the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting ~/Library/Preferences/com.oleganza.gitbox.plist resolved the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problems with gitbox after xcode updates. This worked for me, these directions are from the app author:

1. Quit Gitbox.
2. Delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.oleganza.gitbox.plist
3. Run in Terminal: defaults delete com.oleganza.gitbox
4. Run in Terminal: git config --global push.default matching
5. Open Gitbox.

You may also need to run "git config push.default matching" in your repository if you have other value for "push.default" there.